# carto.js createlayer SQL

Tags: carto

I have an issue with createLayer. The date has duplicate polygons ( countries) so I ha have included a SQL to group and sum up the the values of those duplicated countries :

**cartodb.createLayer(map, {
user_name: 'migrantreport',
type: 'cartodb',
sublayers: [{
sql: "SELECT country, SUM(dec_16)dec_16 FROM origins_by_country_of_arrival_sp_copy GROUP BY country",**

**cartocss: "#origins_by_country_of_arrival_sp_copy{polygon-fill: #FFFFB2; polygon-opacity: 0.8;line-color: #FFF;line-width: 0.5;line-opacity: 1;}",
}]
}).addTo(map)**

The SQL query  works ( I already test it externally ) but when using the code above it  doesn't work nor  gives any error...

I could group all the polygons beforehand but  I need to keep it like this to perform different queries later where the data needs to be non grouped ..

any suggestion??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make `createLayer` work, you need to add to your query at least `the_geom_webmercator` field. I would also recommend adding the `cartodb_id` and `the_geom` columns. Your query works but you need the the_geom_webmercator to "paint" the geometries of your dataset/layer on the map.

Comment: Thanks Ramiro, I've got it :-) working perfectly . Super helpful.